# How can I make a twitter Bot in python using tweepy which tweets on a specific user tweet?

Tags: python, twitter

```
message = " Truly agreed with you "

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='seo_regio', lang = 'en').items(1):
    try:
     print("Found tweet by:@" + tweet.user.screen_name)
     api.update_status(status = "Truly agreed with you #IndianPolitics", in_reply_to _status_id = tweet.id_str)
     print("responded to @" + tweet.user.screen_name)

    if tweet.user.following == False:
        tweet.user.follow()
        print("following @" + tweet.user.screen_name)
```

Comment: please, indent your code correctly. It is actually unreadable.

Comment: I'm sorry for my code but I'm a newbie can you tell me how to create a Twitter bot that replies a specific username when they tweet

Comment: Make sure that any bot you build follows the automation rules https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation - just autoreplying to random users is not compliant.

Answer (score 1):

To reply to a tweet, you must use `in_reply_to_status_id` as you did, and you have also to mention the user at the beginning of the text :

```
api.update_status(status = "@" + tweet.user.screen_name + " Truly agreed with you #IndianPolitics", in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id_str)
```

Comment: how to mention user at the beginning.do i have to use user_name or user_id?

Comment: A tip is to add a point or any character first : ".@user ..."